# Mixed integer nonlinear programming with gekko python

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gekko, mixed-integer-programming

I want to solve the following optimization problem using Gekko in python 3.7 window version.

**Original Problem**

[image: Original]

Here, x_s are continuous variables, D and Epsilon are deterministic and they are also parameters.

However, since minimization function exists in the objective function, I remove it using binary variables(z1, z2) and then the problem becomes MINLP as follows.

**Modified problem**

[image: Modified]

With Gekko,

(1) Can both **original problem** & **modified problem** be solved?

(2) How can I code summation in the objective function and also D & epsilon which are parameters in Gekko?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both problems should be feasible with Gekko but the original appears easier to solve. Here are a few suggestions for the original problem:

- Use `m.Maximize()` for the objective
- Use `sum()` for the inner summation and `m.sum()` for outer summation for the objective function. I switch to `m.sum()` when the summation would create an expression that is over 15,000 characters. Using `sum()` creates one long expression and `m.sum()` breaks the summation into pieces but takes longer to compile.
- Use `m.min3()` for the min(Dt,xs) terms or [slack variables](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/SlackVariables) `s` with x[i]+s[i]=D[i]. It appears that Dt (size 30) is an upper bound, but it has different dimensions that xs (size 100). Slack variables are much more efficient than using binary variables.

```py
D = np.array(100)
x = m.Array(m.Var,100,lb=0,ub=2000000)
```

The modified problem has 6000 binary variables and 100 continuous variables. There are 2^6000 potential combinations of those variables so it may take a while to solve, even with the efficient branch and bound method of APOPT. Here are a few suggestions for the modified problem:

- Use matrix multiplications when possible. Below is an example of matrix operations with Gekko.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
ni = 3; nj = 2; nk = 4
# solve AX=B
A = m.Array(m.Var,(ni,nj),lb=0)
X = m.Array(m.Var,(nj,nk),lb=0)
AX = np.dot(A,X)
B = m.Array(m.Var,(ni,nk),lb=0)
# equality constraints
m.Equations([AX[i,j]==B[i,j] for i in range(ni) \
                             for j in range(nk)])
m.Equation(5==m.sum([m.sum([A[i][j] for i in range(ni)]) \
                                    for j in range(nj)]))
m.Equation(2==m.sum([m.sum([X[i][j] for i in range(nj)]) \
                                    for j in range(nk)]))
# objective function
m.Minimize(m.sum([m.sum([B[i][j] for i in range(ni)]) \
                                 for j in range(nk)]))
m.solve()
print(A)
print(X)
print(B)
```

- Declare `z1` and `z2` variables as integer type with `integer=True`. Here is more [information on using the integer type](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/IntegerBinaryVariables).
- Solve locally with `m=GEKKO(remote=False)`. The processing time will be large and the public server resets connections and deletes jobs every day. Switch to local mode to avoid a potential disruption.

Comment: Thank you for giving me nice suggestions. I'll try the original version first! I have questions about D(array which has length of 30) and epsilon(matrix whose size is 100x30) which are the parameters. 
(1) Is there any reason to define D as np.array(100) which has length 1? 
(2) Should I use m.Param to define D and epsilons, or should it be enough to just define them as np.array form?
I really appreciate it!

Comment: (1) How is `min(D,x)` computed if they are not the same shape? (2) I recommend that you define `D` and `epsilon` as `np.array()` form. It is more efficient when they are only numerical values and the model does not need to provide analytical gradients for those.

Comment: I think I wrongly stated D. My intention was, D does not depend on scenario s, but does depend only on time t such that D is 30*100 matrix whose columns are same with each other like [a a a a ... a] (a is 30*1 column vector). I really appreciate you and I'll try it!!!